# How to define a class that represents an age group?

Tags: date-range, domain-model

I need to be able to define various age groups, i.e. 10 - 11, 12 - 13, etc.

How can I represent an AgeGroup class such that that the age can appropriately group people together today, tomorrow, and in the future, i.e. today's 11 year old could 12 tomorrow (in which case he would be grouped into the 12-13 group instead of the 10-11 year old group, as he was yesterday).

So far I have this:

```
public class AgeGroup
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public DateRange BirthDateRange { get; protected set; }
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public Status Status { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateRange ApplicableDateRange { get; set; }

    public AgeGroup(Guid id, string name, DateRange birthDateRange,DateRange applicableDateRange)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Status = status;
        BirthDateRange = birthDateRange;
        ApplicableDateRange = applicableDateRange;
    }
}

public class DateRange
{
    public DateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    DateTime _startDate;
    DateTime _endDate;

    public virtual DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return _startDate; }
        set { _startDate = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
    }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return _endDate; }
        set { _endDate = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
    }
}
```

This class defines a range of time where this agegroup is applicable. When the applicable date range is passed, we would need to shift everything in time. But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're thinking of storing the age range within a `person` object of some description, I wouldn't, since (1) it's an easily calculable value from the birth date; and (2) it's not really a property of the object (it *could* be considered so but its transient nature will make things more complex than need be).

Instead, store only the birth date then provide some code which can give an age range based on that birth date and the current date.

You can still have age ranges but the people themselves do not exist "inside" them. Instead, you would be able to pass a person object to a function and have it give you back the relevant range.

And, if possible, the age ranges should be based on *ages* rather than birth dates, since the former is unchanging - you don't have to "move" objects between ranges since that's automatic when their range is calculated from their birth date and the current date.

If that's *not* possible (and it appears from your supplied chart that it may be difficult):
[image]

then you can use birth dates as you currently are but with a slight modification to allow for things to change year to year.

Have a `season` object which has the following fields:

- Start date.
- A collection of `range` objects.

This will allow you to have multiple `season` objects if, for example, the age ranges change in following years. As long as they don't change, you'll only have a single `season` object with a start date of whenever your 2014/15 season starts.

The `range` objects themselves are then a collection of objects of the form:

```
Start birth date  End birth date  Range name
----------------  --------------  ----------
1993-01-01        1993-07-31      U22
1993-08-01        1994-07-31      U21
1994-08-01        1995-07-31      U20
:
2009-08-01        2010-07-31      U5
2010-08-01        2010-12-31      U4
```

Then, in order to find out which age group someone belongs to, you:

- Find the current `season` object, based on the date of the season (usually today, though it's conceivable you may want to look at earlier seasons as well).
- Go through all the range objects for that season until you find one where the persons birth date falls between the start and end dates for the range. If you don't *find* an eligible range, then they're not allowed to play.
- Then extract the range name.

Comment: But as you can see I need to associate certain information with an age range. A name, etc. I didn't show everything but we need to associate certain things with the age range, i.e. ages 10-12 are allowed to do this, 13-14 area allowed to do that, etc. Each age group will have properties associated with it.

Comment: @richard, I understand that but your description of "shifting" things through age groups only makes sense if you're placing things that age _into_ the age group. What I'm stating is that you shouldn't do that. By all means create age groups that have certain properties but the matching of "aging things" (people) against a range should be externalised.

Comment: Right I agree...I'm not going to place "People" into the age group. But what I do need is to have properties on the age group, for example, "CanWatchHorrorMovies". Some age groups can, some can't. A person will be slotted into that age group based on a comparison with that class, and then it will be determined if they are allowed to watch horror movies.

Comment: Okay, then your problem appears to be that you're using birthdates as a key rather than ages. Kids growing up faster notwithstanding, the _age_ of 13 (or whatever) will always be the age at which they can start watching horror movies, regardless of the current date. I suspect you'll solve all your problems if you just use ages instead of birthdates in the ranges.

Comment: It's the definition of the age that's the problem...what is 13? In this case it isn't just "13 years ago". Take a look at this: http://www.usclubsoccer.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/US-CLUB-SOCCER-Age-Group-Chart-2014-15.pdf That's what I'm trying to codify.

Comment: @richard, I've updated the answer with some more "meat", based on the extra information you supplied.

Comment: paxdiablo thanks, this gave me a lot to think about.